# Could not run adb reverse: Command failed adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

Tags: react-native

When i am trying to loadup the Screen for 1st time on my Android Studio emulator by using command react-native run-android this errors shows up:

"Could not run adb reverse: Command failed: adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081"

Comment: don't post text as images

Answer (score -1):

Try closing and restarting everything.I've had that error a few times, and that usually solves it.